# How do I get the PropertyInfo.PropertyType name of a EntityReference type via reflection

Tags: reflection

I am writing a small code generator which would read into an edmx file and create business objects on the base of a template. I am using reflection to spit out the type names.

The problem is when I encounter a property (PropertyInfo) of type Entity Reference, (basically an entity property if there is a referential integrity), the PropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name comes as "EntityReference`1" which is not recognized by the compiler.

PropertyInfo.PropertyType.FullName gives "System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1[[BusinessObjectGenerator.Models.BE_Additional_Info, BusinessObjectGenerator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]", which is also not recognized by the C# compiler.

Now I faced the same problem with the Nullable types. And I found the static method Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) which solved the issue. How do I get the name of type of a property that is an entity type, a name that the C# compiler recognizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic types contain ` in their Name. To get the C# readable name of the type, you will need to first check if it is a generic type using **Type.IsGenericType**. If it is a generic type, then you can use **Type.GetGenericArguments()** to get the list of type arguments to the generic type. By getting their names, you can put together the generic type name like. For example, if the type is

```
Dictionary<int, string>
```

Then, the type name would actually be Dictionary`2. Using GetGenericArguments would return an array with two types (int, and string). From these you can generate the composite name.

Note: Each of the types returned from GetGenericArguments() may itself be a generic type, so you should write this as a recursive algorithm.